# When should I use Resources in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, resx

I recently showed some interest for Roslyn analyzers extensions in Visual Studio to improve my code as much as possible.
One of the hints Roslynator usually show me is to avoid using literal strings in my custom exceptions and prefer Resources.

So after some researches, I'm asking myself, when should I use Resources ?
I can't find any good practices guide or anything explanatory related to it.

Should I create a string resource even when the string is used only one time ?
And what for can I use Resources else-way ?

I may have missed some explanations during my researches, so any redirection or explanations are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use resources rather than hard coded strings (sometime called "magic strings"), you'll be able to use localisation libraries to detect the language/culture of the server and produce a string in that culture. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) gives more information about localisation in .NET Core

Comment: Oh yeah it makes more sense now, I did not thought about this use. Gonna do some researches about this, thanks.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer for folks who find this question in the future. If it helped you, could you please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use resources rather than hard coded strings (sometime called "magic strings"), you'll be able to use localisation libraries to detect the language/culture of the server and produce a string in that culture. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) gives more information about localisation in .NET Core.